# Which word is the closest in meaning to "insouciance" in the given context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, nouns

> **Insouciance**: His insouciance, which was kept in check by the law of custom, had its root, like most other evils, in selfishness
>
> (a) apathy   (b) lassitude   (c) deceit   (d) indecision

To me it *apathy* seems to be correct, but my instructor is of the opinion that *lassitude* is the correct one. Please explain.

**Please Note:** This sentence is taken from [The Fijians: A Study of the Decay of Custom](http://www.nzetc.org/tm/scholarly/name-447483.html),  [chapter XIV, Page number -228](http://www.nzetc.org/tm/scholarly/tei-ThoFiji-t1-body-d14.html), however we don't have access to this source at the time of solving.

Comment: For what it's worth.  I chose *lassitude* before looking at your comments.

Comment: @GEdgar:But the reason? and why 'apathy' is not correct here?

Answer (score 4):

The OED defines it as *carelessness, indifference, unconcern*. Collins Thesaurus offers these alternatives: *nonchalance, light-heartedness, jauntiness, airiness, breeziness, carefreeness*. Neither *apathy* nor *lassitude* seems quite to capture the affected air of effortless disdain which *insouciance* seems to imply. It’s crediting the word with too much to describe it as an evil. I suspect the writer didn’t really know what it meant but threw it in to give the sentence a faintly exotic cast.

Comment: I have added the all the options.